# Filter with ParDo or with Transform?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm working on a pipeline that takes a PCollection from BigQuery `PCollection<TableRow>` and filters it based on a cell value.

Is it better to filter it with a ParDo like in [this example](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do#passing-side-inputs-to-pardo) or should I be using the [`Class Filter<T>`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/Filter#class-filtert)?

Basically I'd like to be able to filter based on personType. For example:

```
if(personType == 'customer') {
  then c.output(outputTableRow);
 }
```

What's the difference, how am I approaching this wrong and what should I try instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are pretty much the same. All of the `Filter` transforms are implemented using a `ParDo` with a `DoFn` much like you mentioned (see [Filter.java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/Filter.java#L66)).

The `Filter` transform exists to be a convenient short-hand for filtering. If it works, it is probably more concise. The only major difference is that the `Filter` transform can *only* filter based on the input element. For example, if you wanted to use a side-input containing a list of elements that should be passed through, then you would need to use a `ParDo`. If you're just filtering on "does this field equal 'customer'", then the `Filter` is probably fine.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, Ben!